# Fantasy-anime show: Human-like aliens aboard spaceship, alien queen had white hair

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'd really appreciate the help, I used to watch this as a kid and want to watch it again unfortunately I can't remember the name of the anime.

Stuff I do remember:

- Aliens that look like humans aboard a ship that contains a few robots which can be controlled by humans
- Queen with white hair
- Handmaid of the queen with dark green hair
- Queen's advisor had orange hair

  - Eventually fought against the queen, in part because he was jealous of one of the robot pilots whom the queen finds favor
- There is another alien race that wants to take over the race that is protected by the queen who also has a robot which was controlled by the queen's advisor.

**What is the name of this show?**

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Exchange! See [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/102999) for some help improving this question.

Comment: First off, around **when did you watch it**? You could have been a kid last year or you might have been born in 1899, but we have no idea.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: Also what language was it in? English? Japanese? Spanish? etc. Do you remember what channel or how you watched it? So the queen's advisor had orange hair, do you remember anything about the outfits? Fought against the queen -- how? Melee? Shooting? a band of people try and overthrow her?